# Button linked to ComboBox to open file explorer

Tags: c#

I have a very basic program to navigate to a network file, however, I want to navigate to certain folders depending on which one the user selects.

I have combo box 1 - County (Dropdown includes UK, Ireland, Spain, USA, India)
combo box 2 is generated depending on the selection from combo 1 (if UK is selected then London, Manchester or Liverpool can be selected, if USA is selected then the user has the option to select New York or San Francisco etc).

When the user selects the office, (London for example), I would like the file explorer to open at the London file share, or if they select New York, it would open at the New York file share.

Currently I have it hard coded to navigate to the correct network folder, but I' not sure how I would change it to navigate to the correct network file depending on the user selection.

```
private void btnNavigateToFolder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {          

            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", "\\\\London.xxx\\Finance");
                
           
        }
```

These are some of the examples of the network folder names I would like to navigate to, depending on the user select for combo 2.
NewYork - \\NewYork.xxx\Finance
Liverpool- \\Liverpool.xxx\Finance

Answer (score 2):

First, define a class to manage each ComboBox item. You must use a class with the Text to show in the combobox and all other information that you want to be available for each item. For example:

```
public class ComboBoxItem
{
    public ComboBoxItem()
    {
    }

    public ComboBoxItem(string text, string path)
    {
        this.Text = text;
        this.Path = path;
    }
    
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Text;
    }
}
```

You can define ComboBoxCityItem and ComboBoxOfficeItem if they have different information but for your case I think we only need the Path part.

Add items to your ComboBox using previous class. You have 3 comboboxes but only use city and office to make the path (if I'm not wrong). So:

```
this.cityComboBox.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem("London", "London.xxx"));
this.officeComboBox.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem("Finance", "Finance"));
```

The text that you return in ToString method is the ComboBox text.

And now, you can make the path getting the selected items in the ComboBoxes:

```
private void btnNavigateToFolder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var city = this.cityComboBox.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem;
    var office = this.officeComboBox.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem;
    if (city != null && office != null)
    {
        var path = $"\\\\{city.Path}\\{office.Path}";
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", path);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Knowing that you are starting, I can explain a bit more detailed.

The combobox is a control that contains objects, any type of object. You can insert into the combobox a string (is an object), but also a more complex class like `ComboBoxItem`. The combobox only show a string for each item: if you insert a `ComboBoxItem` instance, the combobox invoke `ToString` method to get the text to show in the control.

When you work with the items (`Items`, `SelectedItem`...), you know that these objects are `ComboBoxItem` instances. So you can do a cast and work with your class.

You can add items to a combobox from the designer, but these items are strings, not `ComboBoxItem` objects. If you look in the YourForm.designer.cs file, you can see how the designer adds the items. It's simply invoke `Add` or `AddRange` with the items. But you want use your own class (`ComboBoxItem`) so you can't use the designer. You can invoke the `comboBox.Items.Add(...)` in any method of your Form. If you are filling now in the designer, you can do with `ComboBoxItem` in the constructor. Remember delete the items in the designer or you'll have some items as string and other items as `ComboBoxItem`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I'm still learning the ropes with C#, I've followed along, but I've got a little bit lost.
Where should I place the following? I've tired to insert code into the class for city and region but it's not working, maybe I'm inserting it into the wrong place?

this.cityComboBox.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem("London", "London.xxx"));
this.officeComboBox.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem("Finance", "Finance"));